# Similar Strings VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, comparison, similarity

I am trying to compare similar strings in VBA using the like operator but I am not able to.  I want the function to see that ESI Clinical Operations and ESI Commercial Custom/HIX are the same because of the fact that they both start with ESI.  But for some reason it will not do that.  What would be my best option to accomplish this? Thanks in Advance!

```
Function SetInternalClientID()

Sheet9.Activate

Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Set rng2 = FindHeader("CLIENT NAME", Sheet9.Name)

Count = 0

For i = 73 To rng2.Rows.Count

Pattern = Left(rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value, 6)

If Pattern = "Blue S" Or Pattern = "BCBS o" Then
    Pattern = Right(rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value, 7)
ElseIf Pattern = "Health" Then
    Pattern = Left(rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value, 8)
End If

ClientCheck = rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value Like Pattern

If ClientCheck = True Then

MsgBox (rng2.Cells(i, 1) & " Like " & rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value)

Else

MsgBox (rng2.Cells(i, 1) & " NOT LIKE " & rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value & " " & Pattern)

End If

Next i


End Function
```

Comment: You can't use `Like` without a pattern! What's your pattern @Philip?

Comment: @JLILIAman it would be ESI in this case.  I have edited my question with the function I am working on.  I use substring functions to determine a pattern but I am not getting any matches for any of the longer strings like the two I mentioned in the question above.  How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are there any formulas in rng2?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub myTextCheck()

   Dim txtOne As String, txtTwo As String

   txtOne = "ESI Clinical Operations"
   txtTwo = "ESI Commercial Custom/HIX"

   If txtOne Like "ESI*" And txtTwo Like "ESI*" Then

   Debug.Print "they both start with ESI"

   Else
      Debug.Print "not..."

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding some code below which should help you along in the process. It's a UDF that takes a `string` parameter to check and compares it to a pattern. The code splits the pattern into individual words, and checks if any of these words are found in the `text_to_check`.

I'm concerned that it will return false positives. It's clear you're working on a Medical/Insurance spreadsheet. Is it possible that the word "clinical" (for example) will recur multiple times in different rows? [Aetna Clinical, ESI Clinical, etc.] It may be beneficial to better define the terms of a match.

```
Function Modified_Like(strTextToCheck, strPattern) As Boolean
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    strArray = Split(strPattern, " ")

    bFound = False

    For Each itm In strArray
        If InStr(1, strTextToCheck, itm, 1) > 0 Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next itm

    Modified_Like = bFound
End Function
```